# how to sort the valuesof an array in descending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

`var_export($array)` of an array gives me this:

```
array 
    ( 

     0 => array ( 'id_20200514222532' => '4', ), 
     1 => array ( 'id_20200521123813' => '5', ), 
     2 => array ( 'id_20200521125410' => '8', ), 
     3 => array ( 'id_20200523003107' => '3', ), 
     4 => array ( 'id_20200523214047' => '2', ), 

    )
```

It should be sorted in descending order based on the numbers, so first **8**, second **5** and so on...

Comment: That's some odd data.. all the nested arrays only have *one* element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `usort()` for this, a sorter function that accepts a callback for comparing two values

```php
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return reset($b) - reset($a);
});
```

That callback function we gave `usort()` will get two "random" items of the array.
I used `reset($a)` and `reset($b)` to get the first values out of the child arrays, then I compared them with a simple subtraction.

Comment: Perfect. Works great this way